# How to generate random numbers based on parameters?

Tags: java

```
public String generateCustomerID(String id, int digit)
{
   randomGenerator = new Random();
   int index = 0;
   for(int i = 1; i <= digit; i++)
   {
        index = randomGenerator.nextInt(digit)；
   }

}
   return id + index;
```

If i type "AB" in string id and number 6 in int digit, how can i produce something like "AB134246".

Comment: for a start you need to add the random number to the end of the String in each iteration of the loop, also do you want to get a random number between 0 and 9?

Comment: `return id + new Random().ints(digit, 0, 10).mapToObj(String::valueOf).collect(Collectors.joining());`

Comment: suppose you need to generate 6 digit random number. use this code `Random randomGenerator = new Random();
int index = 100000 + randomGenerator.nextInt(900000);`

Comment: Why are you reassigning a class field on every call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the code you have posted this is a working solution:

```
public String generateCustomerID(String id, int digit)
{
   randomGenerator = new Random();
   String index = "";
   for(int i = 1; i <= digit; i++) {
        index += randomGenerator.nextInt(10); //Generate a value between 0 and 9 (inclusive)
   }

   return id + index;
}
```

Comment: Who said OP doesn't want zeros? And what's `numericalPart`? Did you mean `index`? And why would you call `nextInt(digit)`?

Comment: thank you for your suggestion! I've edited the answer, I made a mess before :S

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: Also I was wondering how can i make sure all integer values are unique.